# How can I refresh a fact in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

My goal is simple: to trigger a rule again using the same facts that previously triggered it. How can I refresh a fact to do this quickly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the refresh command to place activations for a rule back on the agenda.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(defrule xy
   (x ?x)
   (y ?y)
   =>)
CLIPS> (assert (x 1) (x 2) (y 1) (y 2))
<Fact-4>
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      xy: f-1,f-4
0      xy: f-2,f-4
0      xy: f-1,f-3
0      xy: f-2,f-3
For a total of 4 activations.
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (agenda)
CLIPS> (refresh xy)
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      xy: f-2,f-3
0      xy: f-1,f-3
0      xy: f-2,f-4
0      xy: f-1,f-4
For a total of 4 activations.
CLIPS>
```